# I can not get data from the json request

Tags: node.js, json, express

I send JSON data to route:

```
 const data=[{name:this.name}]
                //qs.stringify(payload)
                axios
                    .post('/users',{name:this.name})
                    .then(
                        response => {
                               console.log(response.data);
                        }
                    )
                    .catch(
                        // error=>console.log(error)
                    )
```

And try get data:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
        var data = req.body; // here is your data
        var obj=JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(obj.toString());
        res.toString("ok");
    });
```

And I got error 500. 
Why not get the data?

Comment: in ```const data``` try ```axios.post('[your route]/users', ...)```, and ```router.post('/users', ...) ```. Also ```var data = req.body.data```. And do you have bodyParser on already?

Answer (score 0):

Your client side code is fine, except that the constant named `data` is entirely unused. On server-side however, `req.body` almost certainly contains a parsed JSON object (provided you have included a body paring middleware already). If you haven't included any body parsing middleware then `req.body` would be `undefined`.

Additionally, the `toString()` method in `res` doesn't send any response, it simply returns a string representation of the response.

You would need to make following changes to your code:

1. Include a body parsing middleware (eg. body-parser) to your express middleware chain, if one isn't already included.
2. Don't call `JSON.parse(req.body)`. `body-parser` would already have done that. Calling it again will only throw exception, and return 500.
3. To convert an Object to JSON string, use `JSON.stringify()` method. `obj.toString()` will probably only return `[object Object]`.
4. Send response using one of `.send()`, `.json()`, `.end()` methods on `res`. Since you need to send a string back, `res.send("ok")` seems most appropriate.

The changed code should appear something like this:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var data = req.body; // here is your data
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    res.send("ok");
});
```